# Core Data - Find out if a relationship between two objects exists

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, relationship, nsmanagedobject

I'm making an app with a questionnaire in it and I'm using Core Data to hold all of its data.

There are three entities: 
Person (the person taking taking the questionnaire),
Question (the question),
QuestionResult (The result for a question)

Person is linked to QuestionResult which is linked to a Question, all via relationships.

Given a Person and Question entity I want to be able to find if there is a QuestionResult object associated between the two. Can this be done using NSPredicate?

Answer (score 0):

The setup:

```
Person <<------->> Question
Person <-------->> Answer
Question <------>> Answer
```

The solution:

```
NSSet *filtered = [person.answers filteredSetUsingPredicate:
   [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"question == %@", questionObject]];
BOOL thereIsAnAnswer = filtered.count != 0;
```

Or, if you do not need to assign a question to a person unless there is an answer, you can simplify the model:

```
Person <---------->> Answer <<----------> Question;
```

The predicate would be exactly the same.